# Decide if the subset is a basis of the vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> Decide if the subset is a basis of the vector space $V$ and state why.
>
> $$\left\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}\right\} =\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1\\  2\\  1
> \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
> -1\\  3\\  2 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 3\\  1\\ 
> -2 \end{pmatrix}\right\} \text{ in V}= \mathbb{R}^{3}$$

We show it's linear independent and we show something with span I didn't understand? Because in my previous question someone said we need to show both these things but I didn't know what was meant with span here.

So for linear independence, I have calculated the linear system of equation but I will not post it here because it would be too long. But the solutions are good; its linear independent for sure.

$$x\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
2\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 
3\\ 
2
\end{pmatrix}+z\begin{pmatrix}
3\\ 
1\\ 
-2
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$$

$x=y=z=0$

Now that comes what I didn't understand. I think second thing we need to do is to show that the three vectors will span $V$? How is that written in math language? I don't know what's meant by it? Or is that not necessary if we want decide if the subset is a basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basis, S, for a finite dimensional vector space, V, has three properties:
1) The vectors in S are **independent**- that is, no one can be written as a linear combination of the others.
2) The vectors in S **span** V- that is, every vector in V can be written as a linear combination of S.
3) The number of vectors in S is equal to the dimension of V.

Further, any two of those implies the third!

If you have that theorem and have already shown that the vectors are independent, it is sufficient to observe that there are 3 vectors in the set and the dimension of $R^3$ is 3.

If you do not have that theorem, but have shown that the vectors are independent then you need to show that they span $R^3$.  You need to show that, for any vector, $\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}$, there exist numbers, a, b, c, such that $a\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2\\ 1\end{pmatrix}+ b\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 3 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}+ c\begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 1\\ -2\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}$.
  That is the same as the three equations a- b+ 3c= x, 2a+ 3b+ c= y, and a+ 2b- 2c= z.  And it should be easy to see that these will have a solution, for any x, y, z, as long as the determinant of coefficients, $\left|\begin{array}{ccc}1 & - 1 & 3 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & -2\end{array}\right|$, is not equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Three linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ must span the whole space.

Comment: Can I reason this by saying because they are linearly independent?

Comment: A basis, S, for a vector space, V, with dimension n has three properties:

Answer (score 1):

Because of $$\det\left|\begin{array}{ccc}1 & - 1 & 3 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & -2\end{array}\right|=-10\ne0$$ we are sure that this subset is a base.(*If not then a vector is a linear combination of the other two ones so the determinant would be equal to $0$*).